# How to implement factory of Akka actors?

Tags: scala, akka

Let's say I have DAO Actors (CassDaoActor, VerticaDaoActor, etc) that respond to message 'Read'.

First of all, is there a way to express a interface or abstract class that defines the message 'Read' that extending actors should implement?

Now assume it's only at runtime that I could get to know which Actor needs to be created based on the configured db. For example, if configured db is cassandra, I need to create CassDaoActor, etc. This apparently is a typical use case for Factory Method Pattern as we know. I want to understand how can we implement such a thing? Evidently we can't pass "context" around since it looses content outside the scope of the actor.

Please suggest.

What I have tried so far is that I am returning respective props based on the configured db to the actor within which I need to create these actors.

```scala
object `package` {
  val CASS = "cass"
  val VERTICA = "vertica"

  def getDAOProps(db: String): Props = db match {
    case CASS => CassDaoActor.props
    case VERTICA => VerticaDaoActor.props
  }
}


// SupervisorActor
val db = configuredDb()
context.actorOf(getDAOProps(db), db)
```

Comment: Unless you need to preserve a global order over your database operations, I wouldn't go with this approach, since the messages are handled sequentially by the actor, one by one.

Comment: Apparantly, I failed to convey the use case properly. So, the use case is to read which dbs are configured from the appConf file and then provision respective actors.  This behavior is dynamic i.e., the dbs can be configured and unconfigured dynamically. The app takes care of unprovisioning the actors againt the dbs that were unprovisioned. So at no point in time an actor that isn't necessary is kept alive but if a new db is configured respective actor will be brought up.

Comment: Moreover unless implementing Factory Method Patterns for actors is an Anti-Pattern, what is an appropriate way to achieve it is what I am interested in knowing.

Comment: I have written a small blog with my understanding so far in Akka that addresses this question: 
http://www.shivamkapoor.com/blogs/technology/2019/06/25/understanding-factories-to-create-actors-in-akka/